# Form submission to database errors if empty fields

Tags: php

I have a form that submits business information.  We dont always have all the info so I want to have it so that only the Business Name and Contact are required.  The issue I have now is if the email is empty the page errors out.  Give me a 500 error. I am using the !emtpy and trim in the script.

add/index.php

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('Location:https://portal.site.net/');

}

require 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['addsmb'])){


    $businessName = !empty($_POST['businessName']) ? trim($_POST['businessName']) : null;
    $contactName = !empty($_POST['contactName']) ? trim($_POST['contactName']) : null;
    $title = !empty($_POST['title']) ? trim($_POST['title']) : null;
    $phone = !empty($_POST['phone']) ? trim($_POST['phone']) : null;
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
    $url = !empty($_POST['url']) ? trim($_POST['url']) : null;
    $city = !empty($_POST['city']) ? trim($_POST['city']) : null;
    $state = !empty($_POST['state']) ? trim($_POST['state']) : null;
    $outletid = !empty($_POST['outletid']) ? trim($_POST['outletid']) : null;
    $user = !empty($_POST['user']) ? trim($_POST['user']) : null;


    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Phone) AS num FROM smb_leads WHERE Phone = :phone";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':phone', $phone);

    //.
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


   if($row['num'] > 0){
    $_SESSION['error'] = "1";
    header("Location: ../error.php".$qstring);
    exit;
   }

   if(empty($_POST['email'])){
     $email = "No Email";
   }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO smb_leads (Outlet_ID, URL, State, City, DUNS_Name, Contact_Name, Title, Phone, created_by, email) VALUES (:outletid, :url, :state, :city, :businessName, :contactName, :title, :phone,  :user, :email)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':businessName', $businessName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':contactName', $contactName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
    $stmt->bindValue(':url', $url);
    $stmt->bindValue(':city', $city);
    $stmt->bindValue(':state', $state);
    $stmt->bindValue(':outletid', $outletid);
    $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);


    $result = $stmt->execute();


}



// Redirect to the listing page
header("Location: ../index.php".$qstring);
```

form

```
<form action="add/index.php" method="post">

<span style="color: gray; font-size: 12px;" >Fields marked with a * are required </span>

<div class="form-row">
<div class=".form-group.required col-md-4">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="businessName" name="businessName" placeholder="* Business Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactName" name="contactName" placeholder="* Contact Name">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Contact Title">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="* Contact Phone #">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">


<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Company Website">
</div>
</div>




<div class="form-row">


<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="State">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">


<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="outletid" name="outletid" placeholder="Outlet ID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['outlet_id']; ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user" placeholder="* Your Name">
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-1">



</div>
<button type="submit" name="addsmb" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Im guessing my error is somewhere in here.

```
$phone = !empty($_POST['phone']) ? trim($_POST['phone']) : null;
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
```

The script works just fine if i leave everything else blank but the name, business and email.

My Error

```
This page isn’t working portal.site.net is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: If you are getting any errors please add them to the question.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman added my error

Comment: @Funk_Forty_Niner How is this a duplicate of those questions?  Not even the same